# How do I get the locations of the x-ticks on a bar plot created in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a grouped bar chart created from a pandas dataframe. I want to set an axhline across each set of bars, but have it stop just beyond the edges of the bar groups, so I need to find a way to get a list of the xtick locations, and the width of the bars that are plotted, so that I can put the xmin and xmax args into the axhline. If I can't do this, can I set the tick locations in the plot function and use those values?

The only thing I have tried is setting the line locations manually, but the plots I'm making come from dataframes with different numbers of columns, so I don't always have the same number of groups on the chart.

Using `get_xticks` doesn't help me much as it just gives me an array of `[1,2,3]`, which is no use for axhline.

The dataframe is set up like so (the dataframe will always have 3 rows, but has a variable number of columns):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], index=['type1', 'type2', 'type3'], columns=['group1', 'group2', 'group3'])

df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```

Each group has a threshold value which I want to indicate on the graph as a horizontal line, but in some of my cases I have 10 or 11 groups, so I don't want to have lines across the entire plot as it would be unreadable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bars extent from their center position by +/- half the `width`. So a bar group at position `1` with a width of `0.6` extents from `1-0.6/2 = 0.7` to `1+0.6/2=1.3`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], 
                  index=['type1', 'type2', 'type3'], 
                  columns=['group1', 'group2', 'group3'])

width = 0.6
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, width=width)


mean= df.mean(axis=1)

x = np.arange(len(df.columns))
ax.hlines(mean, x - width/2, x + width/2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: does this `width` vary based on `figsize`?

Comment: No, width is in data coordinates.